# Modifying a model in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A custom directive creates a new modified model out of the model for display purposes using a service method.

The problem is that new model isn't registered at all.

`boo` is a custom attribute for the model

Appreciate your kind help.

**Fiddle**

1. https://jsfiddle.net/u24godsh/
2. https://jsfiddle.net/u24godsh/1/ using directive controller

**Template**:

```
<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div my-directive boo="model">
        <div ng-model="newmodel">
            <span>Model: </span>  <b>{{model}}</b> <br/>
            <span>New Model: </span>  <b>{{newmodel || 'undefined'}}</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Directive**

```
App.directive('boo',['myService', function (myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            boo: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.newmodel = myService.modifyModel(scope.boo);
        }
    };
}]).service('myService', function(){
    this.modifyModel = function(model){
        var newModel = [];

        for(var key in model) {
            newModel.push(model[key]);
        }

        return newModel;
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
var ctrls = angular.module('controllers', []);
ctrls.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        a: ['a', 'a1'],
        b: ['b', 'b1']
    };
}]);
```

Comment: With isolated scope of directive, I don't think even boo can be accessible in the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wont work that way because your directive uses isolated scope and without any template specified the directive element content will not get the isolated scope by default. Couple of easy ways to handle by setting the scope on the parent:

```
   scope.$parent.newmodel = myService.modifyModel(scope.boo);
```

Or don't even have an isolated scope (provided you are not going to use the directive multiple times under the same scope level), unless you make the new property name, `newmodel`, configurable.

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var boo = scope.$eval(attrs.boo);
            scope.newmodel = myService.modifyModel(boo);
        }
    };
```

Or do the same with a child scope creation.

```
   return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var boo = scope.$eval(attrs.boo);
            scope.newmodel = myService.modifyModel(boo);
        }
    };
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47hj7xnf/)**

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you should really be defining the contents of your directive as its template. For an inline example:

```
App.directive('boo',['myService', function (myService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            boo: '='
        },
        template: '<div><span>Model: </span><b>{{boo}}</b><br/><span>New Model: </span><b>{{newmodel || \'undefined\'}}</b></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.newmodel = myService.modifyModel(scope.boo);
        }
    };
}]);
```

This also solves your scope problems :)

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u24godsh/2/